# I can't get the value of option in select with settings api wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, select

Hello I try to make selectbox with settings api on Wordpress. I think everything is working awesome except `$options` variable. This variable doesn't get settings fields value. But `$options` have to get value after saving. What is the problem?

Register and settings field:

```
add_settings_field (
    'slideral',                 // ID used to identify the field throughout the theme
    'Slider:',                  // The label to the left of the option interface element
    'slider_callback',          // The name of the function responsible for rendering the option interface
    'slider_dizi',              // The page on which this option will be displayed
    'page_1_section',           // The name of the section to which this field belongs
    array(                      // The array of arguments to pass to the callback. In this case, just a description.
        'This is the description of the option 1',
    )
);
register_setting(
    'setting-group-1',
    'slideral'
);
```

Callback:

```
function slider_callback() {

    $categories = get_categories();

    $options = esc_attr( get_option( 'slideral' ) );

    ?>
    <select id="slideral_select" name="slider_dizi">
      <?php
          foreach ($categories as $category ) { ?>
                <option value="<?php echo  $category->name; ?>" <?php if( $options == $category->name) { echo 'selected="selected"'; }?>><?php echo $category->name; ?></option>
        <?php  }
      ?>
      </select>
    <p class="description"> Slider'da görülmesini istediğiniz kategoriyi seçiniz </p>

    <?php


}
```

--------------------------- EDİT ---------------------------------------

```
add_settings_section(
    'page_1_section',         // ID used to identify this section and with which to register options
    'Header Ayarları',                  // Title to be displayed on the administration page
    'header_section_callback', // Callback used to render the description of the section
    'slider_dizi'                           // Page on which to add this section of options
);
```

AND TABS :

```
function my_menu_page() {
    ?>
    <?php
    if( isset( $_GET[ 'tab' ] ) ) {
        $active_tab = $_GET[ 'tab' ];
    } else {
        $active_tab = 'anasayfa';
    }
    ?>
    <div class="wrap">
        <h2> Tema Ayarları </h2>
        <div class="description"> Temanızın ayarlarını bu sayfa içerisinde düzenleyebilirsiniz </div>
        <?php settings_errors(); ?>

        <h2 class="nav-tab-wrapper">
            <a href="?page=tema&tab=anasayfa" class="nav-tab <?php echo $active_tab == 'anasayfa' ? 'nav-tab-active' : ''; ?>"> Anasayfa </a>
            <a href="?page=tema&tab=iletisim" class="nav-tab <?php echo $active_tab == 'iletisim' ? 'nav-tab-active' : ''; ?>"> İletişim </a>
        </h2>

        <form method="post" action="options.php">
            <?php
                if( $active_tab == 'anasayfa' ) {
                    settings_fields( 'setting-group-1' );
                    do_settings_sections( 'slider_dizi' );

                } else if( $active_tab == 'iletisim' )  {
                    settings_fields( 'setting-group-2' );
                    do_settings_sections( 'my-menu-slug-2' );
                }
            ?>

            <?php submit_button(); ?>
        </form>
    </div>
    <?php
}
```

Comment: can you please share your full code? which include `add_settings_section`  also? and can you able to view select box?

Comment: Firstly, Thank you for helping.I add something but I use settings api the first time. Do you need anything ?